# create xml from text file using jaxb

Tags: xml, jaxb

I have a text file and I want it to be converted in xml using jaxb. Please help.
my text file is :

```
     101,2014-06-16T00:30:00Z,10,true
```

my xml format will be:

```
    -<Meter>
     <Name>12345678</Name>
     -<SeriesList>
     -<Series>
     <Name>A+</Name>
     <ValueType>1</ValueType>
     <ValueList>
     -<Value>
     <Value>101</Value>
       <Time>2014-06-16T00:30:00Z</Time>
       <ValueStatus>10</ValueStatus>
       <IsConsumption>true</IsConsumption>
     </Value>
     </ValueList>
     </Series>
     </SeriesList>
     </Meter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create classes Meter, Series and Value:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Meter {
}

class Series {
}

class Value {
}
```

Add properties to each class and annotate them with `@XmlELement` and `@XmlWrapperElements` as appropriate.

Read the input file and split each line using a `StringTokenizer` that has a comma as delimiter. Create a `Value` instance for each line.

Create a `JAXBContext` with `Meter` as the only member of the list of bound classes. Create a `Marshaller` and marshal the meter instance.

Comment: I am able to create upto the ValueList tag. After that I am stuck.Please help me.